# Lists and references

Tags: python

First of all please accept my apologize for this basic question If It was. I have a real coding issue but just for the example I'd like to show you the code above. I'd like to understand why the first code is acting as`boardI` and `board` were pointing on the same reference and how to make the first code only modify `boardI` ?

```
board = []

board.append(["0"] * 10)

boardI = list(board)
boardI[0].append("1")
print board
print boardI

>>[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']]
>>[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']]
```

---

```
board = []

board.append(["0"] * 10)

boardI = list(board)
boardI.append("1")
print board
print boardI

>>[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
>>[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], '1']
```

If I had declared `boardI` as `boardI = board` I'd have undertood but since `boardI = list(board)` it seems I missed something

Comment: You may have a look at `copy.deepcopy()`.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me a lot :)